# Beautiful soup scrape - login credentials not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape a page with login credentials.

```
payload = {
    'email': '*******@gmail.com',
    'password': '***'
}

urls = []

login_url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/signin/'
url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/contracts/breakdown/2010/'
webpage = requests.get(login_url, payload)
content = webpage.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
a = soup.find('table',{'class':'datatable'})
urls.append(a)
```

This is my first time scraping a page with credentials, and can't seem to figure out how to properly enter them.

looked at: http://3.python-requests.org/user/advanced/#session-objects
looked at: https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html
looked at several stackoverflow answers as well.

I searched for a csrf token on the source page and nothing comes up.  I know that scraping  page with a login is specific to each website; can anybody inspect this particular login site and see where I can improve this code?

Comment: try ```requests.post``` instead of get

Comment: I can see from attempting a login on the site that the login URL should be `https://www.spotrac.com/signin/submit/` and that it should be a post request. You will need to extract some sort of token or cookie from the response to do any subsequent requests although I can't see more without a valid login.

Comment: @RobP thanks for your response.  If I were to get you login credentials, do you think you would be able to explore further?

Comment: I think an easier route forward here for you might be to use a tool such as selenium which would perform any JavaScript execution for you and keep track of cookies. Essentially that is what is required here and your existing logic would work pretty quickly with a tool like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is that it uses cookie with Google Analytics, and requests doesn;t receive those to use in the headers. However you can get those cookies by logging in using Selenium. Once you get the cookies that way, you can then use that with the `requests` module to go through the pages.

I haven't exactly figured out how to work around the popup ads (so sometimes this will work, sometimes you'll need to try to run it again), but it seems like once you get past the initial log in, it'll work. Since it does have to go to every players link, it does take about 2-3 minutes or some to run through the total list of 375 players from 2010-2020:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

# Use Selenium to login and get all cookies 
loginURL = 'https://www.spotrac.com/signin/'
username = 'xxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxx'


driver.get(loginURL)

try:
    # Wait for cookie message
    accept_cookie = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cookie-alert-accept']))
    accept_cookie.click()
    print("Cookies accepted")
except TimeoutException:
    print("no alert")

try:
    # Wait for cookie message

    popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 0.25).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.cls-btn']))
    popup.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("timed out")


time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)

submit = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="contactForm"]/div[2]/input')))
submit.click()
print ('Logged in!')



# Now that the cookies are there, can use requests to iterate through the links
for seas in range(2020, 2009, -1):
    print(seas)
    url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/contracts/breakdown/%s/' %seas

    driver.get(url)

    playerDict = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    players = soup.find_all('td',{'class':'player'})
    for player in players:
        name = player.find('a').text
        link = player.find('a')['href']

        if name not in playerDict.keys():
            playerDict[name] = link

results = pd.DataFrame()
count = 1    
for player, link in playerDict.items():

    driver.get(link)

    dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for i, table in enumerate(dfs):
        if len(table.columns) == 2 and len(table) == 5:
            idx = i
            temp_df = table.T
            temp_df.columns = temp_df.iloc[0]
            temp_df = temp_df.rename(columns={'Average Salary:':'Avg. Salary:','Avg Salary:':'Avg. Salary:'})



            try:
                seasonContract = dfs[idx-2].iloc[0,0]
                year = re.findall(r"\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d",seasonContract)[0]
                seasonContract = year + ' ' + re.split(year, seasonContract)[-1]
            except:
                seasonContract = 'Current Contract'

            temp_df['Player'] = player
            temp_df['Contract Years'] = seasonContract
            df = df.append(temp_df.iloc[1:], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)

    results = results.append(df,sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    print ('%03d of %d - %s data aquired...' %(count, len(playerDict), player))
    count += 1



driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.head(25).to_string())
0                Contract: Signing Bonus: Avg. Salary: Signed Using: Free Agent:         Player         Contract Years
0    2 yr(s) / $48,500,000              -  $24,250,000          Bird  2016 / UFA    Kobe Bryant             2014-2015 
1    3 yr(s) / $83,547,447              -  $27,849,149          Bird         0 /    Kobe Bryant             2011-2013 
2   7 yr(s) / $136,434,375              -  $19,490,625           NaN  2011 / UFA    Kobe Bryant             2004-2010 
3    5 yr(s) / $56,255,000              -  $11,251,000           NaN  2004 / UFA    Kobe Bryant             1999-2003 
4     3 yr(s) / $3,501,240              -   $1,167,080           NaN         0 /    Kobe Bryant  1996-1998 Entry Level
5     2 yr(s) / $2,751,688              -   $1,375,844       Minimum  2014 / UFA  Rashard Lewis             2012-2013 
6    1 yr(s) / $13,765,000              -  $13,765,000           NaN         0 /  Rashard Lewis             2012-2012 
7   6 yr(s) / $118,200,000              -  $19,700,000           NaN  2013 / UFA  Rashard Lewis             2007-2012 
8    4 yr(s) / $32,727,273              -   $8,181,818           NaN  2007 / UFA  Rashard Lewis             2003-2006 
9    3 yr(s) / $14,567,141              -   $4,855,714           NaN  2003 / UFA  Rashard Lewis             2000-2002 
10      2 yr(s) / $672,500              -     $336,250           NaN  2000 / RFA  Rashard Lewis  1998-1999 Entry Level
11   2 yr(s) / $10,850,000              -   $5,425,000          Bird  2017 / UFA     Tim Duncan             2015-2016 
12   3 yr(s) / $30,361,446              -  $10,120,482          Bird  2015 / UFA     Tim Duncan             2012-2014 
13   4 yr(s) / $40,000,000              -  $10,000,000           NaN  2012 / UFA     Tim Duncan             2010-2011 
14  7 yr(s) / $122,007,706              -  $17,429,672           NaN  2010 / UFA     Tim Duncan             2003-2009 
15   3 yr(s) / $31,902,500              -  $10,634,167           NaN  2003 / UFA     Tim Duncan             2000-2002 
16   3 yr(s) / $10,239,080              -   $3,413,027           NaN  2000 / UFA     Tim Duncan  1997-1999 Entry Level
17   2 yr(s) / $16,500,000              -   $8,250,000          Bird  2017 / UFA  Kevin Garnett             2015-2016 
18   3 yr(s) / $36,000,000              -  $12,000,000          Bird  2015 / UFA  Kevin Garnett             2012-2014 
19   3 yr(s) / $51,300,000              -  $17,100,000           NaN  2012 / UFA  Kevin Garnett             2009-2011 
20  5 yr(s) / $100,000,000              -  $20,000,000           NaN  2009 / UFA  Kevin Garnett             2004-2008 
21  6 yr(s) / $126,016,300              -  $21,002,717           NaN         0 /  Kevin Garnett             1998-2003 
22    3 yr(s) / $5,397,120              -   $1,799,040        Rookie         0 /  Kevin Garnett  1995-1997 Entry Level
23    1 yr(s) / $1,308,506              -   $1,308,506           NaN  2012 / UFA   Michael Redd       Current Contract
24   6 yr(s) / $90,100,000              -  $15,016,667           NaN  2011 / UFA   Michael Redd             2005-2010 
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi for do a login I do:

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}
     try:

        url = 'https://empresa.computrabajo.com.mx/login'
        r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#the page in the login have a hiden attribute call token for do the login
        token = soup.find("input", attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'}).get('value')
        login_data = {
            '__RequestVerificationToken': token,
            'UserName': 'YOURUSERNAME',
            'Password': 'YOURPASS',
            'KeepMeLoggedIn': 'false'
        }
        r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    except Exception as getError:
        print('Error Login')
```

you can find a lot of information in youtube, to see how using the network tool in google chrome can catch he headers and url that need to use in a login page of your interest.