# Beautifulsoup requests.post not scraping correctly

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape a site that requires a login:

```
login_url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/signin/'
data = {
        'email': 'a****@gmail.com',
        'password': '******'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = requests.post(login_url , data)
    index_page= s.get('https://www.spotrac.com/nba/contracts/breakdown/2010/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(index_page.text, 'html.parser')
```

This code will scrape the page, but only as if you hadn't logged in - ie there is none of the data being returned that you would expect with an accurate login.

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Your session never receives the cookies from your first request.. Perhaps you mean to write `s.post(login_url, data)`?

Comment: @Brian I changed to s.post; the same result occurs

Comment: Is the only change between this question and [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60647183/beautiful-soup-scrape-login-credentials-not-working) the addition of the POST request? Have you learned anything new about the problem in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are sending your username and password to the wrong URL. `https://www.spotrac.com/signin` is the page that shows the login fields, but `https://www.spotrac.com/signin/submit/` is the page your credentials get sent to when you click submit.

I was not able to test this code because I don't want to pay $30

```
login_url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/signin/submit/'
data = {
        'email': 'a****@gmail.com',
        'password': '******'
}

with requests.session() as s:
    response = requests.post(login_url , data)
    index_page= s.get('https://www.spotrac.com/nba/contracts/breakdown/2010/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(index_page.text, 'html.parser')
```